# AND and OR function in one query, not working? sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select

i run a query with a WHERE

"COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT1 = 0  OR COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT2 = 0 AND COMPUTERCLASSROOM_DONE = 1"

though it return all the row that met a requirement..this is the table rows data

According to column presentation, here are the values of the rows

```
ROW 1 =                0                       0                          0    
ROW 2 =                1                       0                          0   
ROW 3 =                1                       2                          1   
ROW 4 =                1                       3                          0   
ROW 5 =                1                       4                          1   
ROW 6 =                0                       5                          1   
ROW 7 =                0                       0                          1
```

they all return..why is that? if i changed the OR with an AND, it would follow the query, returning ROW 7... its just weird..i need that OR and AND in one query, because my target is to return a row with at least 0 in either SLot1 or Slot2, and DONE = 1

Comment: Parentheses. Use them. They don't hurt. I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
WHERE (COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT1 = 0 OR COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT2 = 0) AND 
       COMPUTERCLASSROOM_DONE = 1
```

Comment: wow, silly me, overlooked that, i thought it was ok in sql to do that..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @Jack already pointed out, the problem is because you are not using the parentheses. And hence your query is evaluated logically different from what you are expecting.

Try @JW.'s snippet and it would work perfectly.

```
WHERE (COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT1 = 0 OR COMPUTERCLASSROOM_SLOT2 = 0) AND (COMPUTERCLASSROOM_DONE = 1)
```

Comment: you parenthetising lack logic. you put them around the OR operation in one case, and around an '=' comparison in another case, but not around the 2 other '=' comparisons.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance sir, but I am not sure if I understand.

Answer (score 1):

*Underlying cause*

AND is evaluated as a multiplication; OR is evaluated as an addition. So according to arithmetic precedence rule (PEMDAS), AND is evaluated before evaluating OR.

```
Example: 1 OR 0 is 1 + 0 = 1; 1 AND 0 is 1 * 0 = 0;
```

So

```
X or X or X and X is grouped automatically as X or X or (X and X).
```

Use of parenthesis avoids the confusion, as well as makes code more readable.